# integrating ZXing barcode reader in symbian

Tags: camera, symbian, zxing, s60

I am trying to integrating ZXing barcode in my symbian application but i its working
only in the UI class but i want to integrate in listbox view so that when i click 
list item Zxing has to open. is this possible?
anybody have idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to open zxing camera view when clicking listbox item?
Then you need to catch listbox event

```
void CCasesContainer::HandleListBoxEventL(CEikListBox* aListBox, TListBoxEvent aEventType) {  
    if ((aEventType == MEikListBoxObserver::EEventEnterKeyPressed)  
        || (aEventType == MEikListBoxObserver::EEventItemClicked)) {  
    TInt currentItem(iListBox->CurrentItemIndex());  
    // open the zxing view smth like  
    DeactivateActiveViewL();  
    CAknViewAppUi::ActivateLocalViewL(TUid::Uid(zxingView));  
    }
}
```

To learn more how views work in symbian start from [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/S60_application_views) or [there](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/S60_View_Architecture_with_UI_Design)

Comment: thank you shtolik now camera is opening when i click list box item but when i press back and activating previous view its switching back but camera is still running in backgroung how to close camera?